# Are there any libraries for drawing a neural network in Python?

Tags: python, neural-network

I'd like to render a neural network in Python to make sure it is set up properly.  I'd like to verify that it has the correct # of nodes, correct edge configuration, and perhaps even correct edge weights after training.  I'd like to visually debug simple examples by printing them to a PNG/JPG but do not know any libraries that do this.  Is there a library for drawing a neural network for visual debugging?

(Such a library would of course make assumptions on the data types/structures - e.g., assuming the neural network comes from Theano, TensorFlow, or some other library.  I'm flexible on the assumptions made.)

Comment: [TensorBoard: Graph Visualization](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/graph_viz/index.html). [Example](http://blog.altoros.com/visualizing-tensorflow-graphs-with-tensorboard.html).